# Problem compiling Linux source

Tags: linux, qt

I am trying to compile Linux source but always get qt missing, here is a output

```
[root@localhost linux-2.6.32.5]# yum install qt3
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package qt3-3.3.8b-25.fc11.i586 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@localhost linux-2.6.32.5]# make xconfig
  CHECK   qt
*
* Unable to find the QT3 installation. Please make sure that
* the QT3 development package is correctly installed and
* either install pkg-config or set the QTDIR environment
* variable to the correct location.
*
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `scripts/kconfig/.tmp_qtcheck', needed by `scripts/kconfig/qconf.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
[root@localhost linux-2.6.32.5]# echo $QTDIR
/usr/lib/qt-3.3
[root@localhost linux-2.6.32.5]#
```

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be that the qt3 package you are installing contains just the libraries, but not the header files? Maybe you have to install package qt3-devel or something similar for your linux distribution...

Comment: +1, "Please make sure that 
* the QT3 development package is correctly installed and
"

Comment: Bingo, that's it. It's definitely the qt3-devel package on Red Hat based systems.